# How can I convert the tables and math in a latex document to one of the markup languages supported by github's wiki?

Tags: tables, conversion, org-mode, markdown

I wrote some software documentation in Latex, but need to get it into a more lightweight format.

I used pandoc to convert latex to markdown, but it did not do a very good job of converting tables.

Here is minimal example of what I want to convert:

```
\documentclass[12pt,english]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{lllp}
    \hline
    \textbf{do}   &  re &$\sqrt{\frac{1}{N}}$ &me  \\
    \textbf{fa}   & so & $\frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}$& la\\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

and this is the result of `pandoc -o foo.md foo.tex:

```
lllp

**do** & re &$\sqrt{\frac{1}{N}}$ &me    **fa** & so & $\frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}$& la
```

But this does not render as a table in markdown.

Github's wiki supports all of the following markup languages (solutions for converting tables to markdown or languages in bold would be preferred):

- AsciiDoc
- Creole
- **Markdown**
- **Org-mode**
- Pod
- Rdoc
- **Textile**
- reStructuredText

Is there a way to convert my latex tables to any of these (automagically, without having to re-typset the math)? I really do not want to use the embedded images as provided by `latex2html`.

Comment: As far as I can see none of the languages that you list support math, and a quick google search suggests that you can not access javascript so mathjax is not an option, so it may be that images are your only option for mathmatics

Comment: Perhaps file a bug at pandoc mailing list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can see, none of the languages that you list support math, and a quick google search suggests that you can not access JavaScript so MathJax is not an option, so it may be that images are your only option for mathematics.